# Unable to change my email address (email already exists... somewhere?)

Tags: support, status-completed

Today I created an account to post a question.  I thought I had maybe created one a couple years back, but I wasn't sure, so here's what I did:

1. I went to create an account, saw that I had four options for authentication, so I chose to use my Google account (thinking if I already used this account sometime in the past, it would've stated as much)
2. This successfully created a new account and gave me an ugly, auto-generated username, so I decided to change it.
3. I clicked "edit" in my profile, specified a new username, and it said "Sorry, this e-mail address already exists."  (that's not what I was attempting to change!)
4. It became clear that I needed to specify a *different* email address if I wanted any hope of changing my username, which I did.  I was then able to change my username.
5. Now I cannot change my email address back to my Google (gmail) address.

I thought maybe I had created an account in the past, before the Google account linkage was possible, so I tried signing in to the Stack Exchange with my @gmail address, and with OpenID, and both said no account exists w/ my that address.  I'm not sure where else I may have created an account, but somewhere there is a conflict.

Any thoughts on how I can track down this orphaned account?

Rick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had an old account on Stack Overflow (registered with MyOpenID).

I merged it into your new account, so you should be all set.